# CS50 Problem set 5 speller trie data structure issues - Using fscanf to copy strings from file into trie?

Tags: c, cs50, trie

I successfully implented a hash table for this problem, however I want to try and implement a trie instead. Unfortunately when I run check50 I get the following error messages:

```
:) dictionary.c, dictionary.h, and Makefile exist
:) speller compiles
:( handles most basic words properly
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:( handles min length (1-char) words
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:( handles max length (45-char) words
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:( handles words with apostrophes properly
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:( spell-checking is case-insensitive
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:( handles substrings properly
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

The log for the first error message is:

```
:( handles most basic words properly
Cause
expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
Log
running ./speller basic/dict basic/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 0\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 8\nWORDS IN TEXT: 9\n"...

Expected Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS


WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8
WORDS IN TEXT:        9

Actual Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS

The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```

From these error messages I'm thinking that the issue is either with my load function or check function.

Like with the hashtable implementation, I've used fscanf to copy each word from the file to be opened into a temporary buffer, and then copy this into the trie. However other methods I have seen seem to use fgetc which seems more inefficient to me.

Is the issue with the method I've used to transcribe the strings from the files or is a seperate logic issue?

Here is my full code:

dictionary.c (what I've written)

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Decalre trie node struct
typedef struct trie
{
    bool isLeaf;
    struct trie* children[Alphabet_size];
}
trie;

//Declare root node globally
trie* root_node;

// Declare word globally
char string[LENGTH + 1];

// Keep track of number of words in dictionary
int dict_size = 0;

// Function that gets new trie node
struct trie* getNewTrieNode(void)
{
    // Malloc memory for new trie node and check pointer != NULL
    struct trie* node = malloc(sizeof(trie));
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        // Set isLeaf Boolean to false
        node->isLeaf = false;
        // Initialise all 26 child pointers to NULL
        for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet_size; i++)
        {
            node->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //Open dictionary.h file
    FILE *dict_ptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    // Check to see if dictionary.h file pointer is NULL
    if (dict_ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open %s", dictionary);
        return false;
    }
    // Create array of chars into which we can temporarily store each word
    char buffer[LENGTH + 1];
    // Dynamically allocate memory for universal root node
    root_node = malloc(sizeof(trie));
    // Loop over whole file to copy each string until we reach EOF
    while (fscanf(dict_ptr, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        // Insert word into Trie data structure
        // Create pointer to root_node in order to traverse data structure
        struct trie* current_node = root_node;
        int j = strlen(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            // Create new node if child pointer does not point to path
            if (current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] = getNewTrieNode();
            }
            //Go to next node if child pointer points to one
            current_node = current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'];
            // Move to next character in string
            buffer[i]++;
        }
        dict_size++;
    }
    fclose(dict_ptr);
    return true;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char* word)
{
    // Make lowercase copy of word (so it will match path of corresponding word from dictionary)
    int n = strlen(word);
    char word_copy[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        word_copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    // Add NULL terminating character to lowercase copy of word
    word_copy[n] = '\0';
    // Search Trie data structure for lowercase copy of word
    // Return false if Trie is empty
    if (root_node == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Declare pointer to root_node to traverse Trie data structure
    struct trie* current_node = root_node;
    // Declare integer the length of the lowercase copy of word
    int k = strlen(word_copy);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        // Go to next node
        current_node = current_node->children[word_copy[i] - 'a'];
        // If current_node pointer is NULL we have reached the end of the path and the string has not been found
        if (current_node == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Move to next character in string
        word_copy[i]++;
    }
    // If we have gotten through whole string, current node must be Leaf Node corresponding to that string
    return (current_node->isLeaf);
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return dict_size;
}

// Prototype for destroy trie data structure function
void destroy(struct trie* root_node);

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    destroy(root_node);
    return true;
}

// Destroys entire trie data structure recursively and frees dynamically allocated memory
void destroy(struct trie* root)
{
    // Initialise current node to point to root node to traverse trie data structure
    struct trie* current_node = root_node;
    // Recursively delete entire trie data structure
    for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet_size; i++)
    {
        if (current_node->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            destroy(current_node->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(current_node);
}
```

The next two files are distribution code I don't alter:

dictionary.h

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45
#define Alphabet_size (26)

// Prototypes
struct trie* getNewTrieNode(void);
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you don't write the expected output... You seem to write a list of words, but the checker seems to expect some kind of statistics output.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Passing the posted code through a compiler results in several warnings AND an error because the `typedef` for the struct is using a value:  `Alphabet_size` which is not defined

Comment: What is the contents of the 'home grown' header file: `dictionary.h`?

Comment: where is `LENGTH` defined?

Comment: the function: `getNewTrieNode()` can return NULL, however the code never checks for that condition in the `load()` function, BUT treats the allocated memory as if the call were always successful.  This will result in a seg fault event when the function: `getNewTrieNode()` fails

Comment: in the function: `load()`, this statement: `root_node = malloc(sizeof(trie));` needs to have the returned value checked (!=NULL).  The posted code 'assumes' that the call to `malloc()` was successful. However, that is not a safe assumption and will result in a seg fault event when the call fails.

Comment: regarding: `int j = strlen(buffer);`  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: @user3629249 I've added the header file main program to the post. I'll work through your other suggestions now.

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(dict_ptr, "%s", buffer) != EOF)`  There are several other reasons this statement can fail besides EOF.  In general, it is best to check for success.  The function: `fscanf()` returns the number of successful input format conversion specifiers (I.E. the `%s`) so should be checking for ==1.  Suggest: ` while ( fscanf( dict_ptr, "%s", buffer) == 1 )

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            if (current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] = getNewTrieNode();
            }
            current_node = current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'];
           ...
        } in function: `load()` This creates a new node for each character in the word, Now what you want to do.

Comment: regarding: `int j = strlen(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)`  the `buffer[]` contains a NUL termination character, so a better statements would be: `for( int i=0; buffer[i]; i++ )`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");`  and similar statements:  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout.  The program could be executed under any name.  suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s [DICTIONARY] text\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: There are plenty of other problems in the posted code, but the above comments should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: @user3629249 Cheers for all the suggestions they all make much more sense than what I already had. After changing them I still have the same problem however. Regarding ```for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)         {             if (current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] == NULL)             {                 current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'] = getNewTrieNode();             }             current_node = current_node->children[buffer[i] - 'a'];            ...         } in function:``` does that not only create a new node for the character in the word if the child == NULL?

Comment: @user3629249 I can only change code from dictionary.c. The header file dictionary.h and speller.c were written by the course coordinators and I'm not to change those